# How to access Amazon S3 backup without Jungle Disk

Tags: amazon-s3, jungledisk

I've been backing up my Mac to the Amazon S3 cloud using Jungle Disk. Now that Mac is dead. Fine, my backups are on the cloud. So, I go to my other Mac and download Jungle Disk. It is a workgroup version of the software. When I run it it wants me to verify that I purchased the software. Well, when I first set up the Jungle Disk client some years ago there was a free client. I'd rather not pay for this unless there's no good alternative.

Next I login to my Amazon S3 Console. I have a bunch of buckets there which are impossible to navigate.

So, I google around for S3 browsers and find Cyberduck. I download and install that. When I run it it wants a server URL. At this point I'm stuck.

Is there a client that knows about the structure of backups in S3 that I can install on this other Mac to get to my backed up data?

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of conversations with Jungle Disk support I was given this (undocumented) url:

https://downloads.jungledisk.com/jungledisk/JungleDiskDesktop3160.dmg

I've downloaded and installed the client, didn't have to pay anything, and I've gotten to my backed up data. Whew!

Comment: Tried the same today, but unfortunately this application prompts me for a username/password and then tells me I don't have a valid subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Sol got his stuff fixed. Sharing additional background for future readers. Jungle Disk uses the WebDAV standard to allow access through our web service layer. Depending on the version of Jungle Disk you're running we have a few different URLs you'll authenticate to. Ping our team at support.jungledisk.com and we'll get you setup.